# Create a nested dictionary using recursion Python

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to wrap my head around how recursion works, particularly how you can break it down into sub parts and work on that while maintaining that it all belongs to one overall part, if that makes any sense.

So for example: if I am given a list like [1,2,3,4,5] and I want to write a function that continuously creates a dictionary within a dictionary with each element in the list being the key; the output being like this - {1:{2:{3:{4:{5:{}}}}}}.

I know it can be done with a simple for loop but the point is I want to learn how recursion works. Here is what I tried and I know it's probably pretty far off. :(

```
data = [1,2,3,4,5]
split_order = dict()

def split(data, split_order):
  if len(data) == 0:
      return split_order
  else:
      attr = data[0]
      new_data = data[1:]
      split_order[attr] = dict()
      split_order[attr] = split(new_data, split_order[attr])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understood recursion is difficult. So to make it a little simpler I simplified the code (I removed the second parameter, you do not need it):

```
def split(data):
  if len(data) == 0:
      return data #trivial case, we have no element therefore we return empty list
  else: #if we have elements
      first_value = data[0] #we take the first value
      data = {first_value : split(data[1:])} #data[1:] will return a list with every value but the first value
      return data #this is called after the last recursion is called
```

If you call it with `split[1,2,3,4,5]` it returns `{1: {2: {3: {4: {5: []}}}}}`

Let's see what we have. We have the part that breaks the recursion, this is often called the anchor (at least in my language).
We simply check if the data is empty. You did that part as well.

The second part will extract the first value and call the split but with a shorter list. Usually this part will work on the provided data and then call itself. It is advantageous if the data (list) is constantly getting smaller so that the anchor can be called at some time in the future. So usually you remove one or more items.

If we step trough the code we can see what the recusion is calling. If our input is `[1,2,3]` we call:
`split([1,2,3]) -> split([2,3]) -> split([3]) -> split()`
Only after the last call is done we start to return the values (in this order):
`[] -> {3: []} -> {2: {3: []}} -> {1: {2: {3: []}}}`

Comment: Little note for the math interested people, a recursion can be compared to the mathematical induction. The base case is the anchor, the induction step the body.

Answer (score 4):

You're not returning anything in your `else` clause.  You also don't need to pass `split_order` into your function:

```
def split(data):
    if data:
        head, *tail = data  # This is a nicer way of doing head, tail = data[0], data[1:]
        return {head: split(tail)}
    else:
        return {}
```