# How to create nested dictionary with process IDs in python

Tags: python, dictionary, tree, nested

I am trying to create a process tree. I have .csv file with two columns in this Parent and Child format. The amount of rows is not set. I want to create a nested dictionary in the format `{Parent : {Child : {}, Child: {}}}` where a Parent a key has a dictionary of its children as a value and those Children have a dictionary of their children.

This is specifically what the input looks like:

- [PPID, PID]
- [PPID, PID]
- [PPID, PID]
- [PPID, PID]
- ...etc

I found a recursive solution here: [Create a nested dictionary using recursion Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52349884/create-a-nested-dictionary-using-recursion-python)

```
def split(data):
  if len(data) == 0:
      return data #trivial case, we have no element therefore we return empty list
  else: #if we have elements
      first_value = data[0] #we take the first value
      data = {first_value : split(data[1:])} #data[1:] will return a list with every value but the first value
      return data #this is called after the last recursion is called
```

However, this doesn't seem to work for me since it would only show one Child for a Parent. I have been looking all over and cannot find a way to do it.

Comment: Are you looking for an optimal solution (in time and/or space)? One method I can think of off the bat is to iterate through data once to get keys for a dictionary, and iterate a second time to get the immediate children for each of the keys (this will give you an adjacency list). After this, initialize a second dictionary and for each key in your first dictionary, follow the path starting at the parent and ending at a leaf node for each child of the parent using DFS. Keep a copy of these paths in your 2nd dictionary. Once you're done, the 2nd dictionary will be what you're looking for.

Comment: Transforming list of dict (id-parent) to see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71555459/15392974

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple algorithms for you to build this tree. The right path will depend on time/space complexity.

My usual go-to solution for that kind of problem usually is using simple loops and recursion, and evolving based on that. Something like:

```py
def build_pid_tree(pid_list, root_pid, result=None):
    if result is None:
        result = {}

    if root_pid not in result:
        result[root_pid] = {}

    for (ppid, pid,) in pid_list:
        if ppid != root_pid:
            continue

        if pid not in result[ppid]:
            result[ppid][pid] = {}

        build_pid_tree(pid_list, pid, result[ppid])

    return result
```

Comment: Hi Gustavo, I do not know if I am doing something wrong, but I am not quite getting the result. I understand how this code works. However, when I run it the loop ends early and only gives me a dictionary with three nodes like so {PPID : {PID : {PID : {} } } }. The third node is a leaf and when it returns I assume the loop should continue but instead it returns again until the whole function ends.

Comment: This should be the case ([here's my running example](https://gist.github.com/gkawamoto/3ba09d03f0efa7149b6bd28286bee6c8). Do you mind sharing the test data you're trying with?